# display html table in meterial-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, material-ui

I'm displaying a list of issues in my browser with this material-ui code:

```
<Paper className={classes.root} elevation={4}>
    <Typography type="title" className={classes.title}>
      All Issues
    </Typography>
    <List dense>
     {this.state.issues.map((item, i) => {
      return <Link target="_blank" to={item.issue_url} key={i}>
                <ListItem button>
                  <ListItemText primary={<div>
                                          <table>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td width="40">{item.issue_state}</td>
                                              <td width="40">{item.issue_number}</td>
                                              <td width="600">{item.issue_title}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </table>
                                         </div>}/>
                  <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                  <IconButton>
                      <ArrowForward/>
                  </IconButton>
                  </ListItemSecondaryAction>
                </ListItem>
             </Link>
           })
         }
    </List>
  </Paper>
```

As you'll see it also has a standard HTML table in it. My 1st question is if there is a better way to do this? Can I create a table structure within a list with material-ui?

The second question is how can I add a single row of column names to the top of my table? I've tried several combinations of `tr`/`td` but the closest I can get to what I want is to have a title row above each list item.

Comment: Table headings use `th` tags. You might have a look into [standard, accessible table markup](https://webaim.org/techniques/tables/data).

Comment: Your first question confuses me. https://material-ui.com/demos/tables/

Comment: Sorry, I meant can I create it within the list or can the list be used in such a way that it displays the data as I want?

Comment: Still not clear. You can embed one component in another and pass in the data as a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved my issue:

```
<Paper className={classes.root} elevation={4}>
    <Typography type="title" className={classes.title}>
      All Issues
    </Typography>
    <Table className={classes.table}>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell width="40">ISSUE STATE</TableCell>
        <TableCell width="40">ISSUE NUMBER</TableCell>
        <TableCell width="600">ISSUE TITLE</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </Table>
    <List dense>
     {this.state.issues.map((item, i) => {
      return <Link target="_blank" to={item.issue_url} key={i}>
                <ListItem button>
                  <ListItemText primary={<div>
                                          <Table className={classes.table}>
                                            <TableRow>
                                              <TableCell width="40">{item.issue_state}</TableCell>
                                              <TableCell width="40">{item.issue_number}</TableCell>
                                              <TableCell width="600">{item.issue_title}</TableCell>
                                            </TableRow>
                                          </Table>
                                         </div>}/>
                  <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                  <IconButton>
                      <ArrowForward/>
                  </IconButton>
                  </ListItemSecondaryAction>
                </ListItem>
             </Link>
           })
         }
    </List>
  </Paper>
```

If there is a better way to do this I'd bee keen to hear it.